# can't open menus in firefox or okular after update. Graphics issue?

Tags: drivers, graphics, firefox

I'm running Kubuntu 16.04, 64 bit, and the built in graphics adapter on my desktop. For some reason,after I updated, I can not open menus in firefox at all  (Can't open settings, add ons menus, etc). Reading around online, I found someone with this exact problem and their solution was "fixed graphics". That tells me nothing... 
Here's what the info for LSPCI shows for my graphics driver:
Display controller: Intel Corporation 4 Series Chipset Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 03)

The driver manager shows there are no proprietary drivers in use or available. I'm connected via HDMI, and also tried VGA, no luck. BIOS settings are unchanged, and as they should be. Chromium works, but Okular has the same issue, no menus at all. My other Kubuntu machine does not have this problem with Okular or the same version of Firefox.

How can I change the graphics adapter driver, or do I just need to go with a graphics card?

Firefox version is 61.0.1

Edit: I have completely purged firefox from the system, refreshed it, etc. still no luck

Comment: when you purged firefox did you remove folders in Home directory? Because it won't help if not.. anyways you don't need to purge firefox you can try to give it a tune-up in firefox click Help/Troubleshooting info. and click refresh firefox if you can't access this option then try firefox from scratch re-install it but before remove cache and config folders of Firefox in Home directory.

Comment: Yes, I searched for every folder related to it and  deleted it, including hidden ones. I also refreshed firefox with no luck

Answer (score 0):

Just got an answer on another forum for this, and it now works. If you change the compositor from openGL to xrender, it solves the problem. These settings on plasma 5 are in settings/systemsettings/ display and monitor